# How to create list of DbParameter?

Tags: c#, list, generics, visual-studio-2005

Why doesn't the following compile in my VS2005?

```
List<DbParameter> params = new List<DbParameter>();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`params` in a [reserved keyword in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Use a different variable name or prefix it with `@`

```
List<DbParameter> @params = new List<DbParameter>();
```

Comment: If I use `@params` in the declaration, do I have to use it thereafter?

Comment: Yes, you always need to use `@params` afterwards where you use that variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable name `params` is a reserved keyword, change it.